# Bootstrap navBar overlap modal fade

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, laravel, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-modal

I have a navbar from bootstrap which I made it has fixed-top and here comes the problem when I get to a modal fade window it overlaps and doesn't let me click on anything.

```
<!-- Navigation bar-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            {{-- <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span> --}}
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{!!URL::to('/')!!}">SCM</a>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li><a href="{!!URL::to('/')!!}">Home <span class="sr-only">(current)</span></a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Contacto</a></li>
                <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-calendar fa-fw"></i> Horarios</a></li>
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown <span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            {{-- LOGIN --}}
            @if(!Auth::check())
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li><a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModal" data-whatever="@getbootstrap"><i class="fa fa-sign-in fa-fw"></i> Login</a>
                    <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                {!!Form::open(['url'=>'login', 'method'=>'POST'])!!}
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Iniciar sesion</h4>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Email:</label>
                                        <input name="email" type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                                    </div>
                                    <div class="form-group">
                                        <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Contraseña:</label>
                                        <input name="password" type="password" class="form-control" id="recipient-password">
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                    {!!Form::submit('Entrar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
                                </div>
                                {!!Form::close()!!}


                                <a class="btn" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#passwordRecover" data-whatever="@getbootstrap"> ¿No recuerdas tu contraseña?</a>
                                    <div class="modal fade" id="passwordRecover" tabindex="0" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
                                        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                                            <div class="modal-content">
                                                {!!Form::open(['url'=>'/password/email', 'method'=>'POST'])!!}
                                                <div class="modal-header">
                                                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">  <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
                                                    <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">No recuerdo mi contraseña</h4>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-body">
                                                    {!! csrf_field() !!}
                                                    <div class="form-group">
                                                        <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Email:</label>
                                                        <input name="email" type="email" value="{{ old('email') }}" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                                                    </div>                                                        
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Cerrar</button>
                                                    {!!Form::submit('Enviar', ['class' => 'btn btn-primary'])!!}
                                                </div>
                                                {!!Form::close()!!}
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div></li>
                </ul>
                @else
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                <li class="dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">{{Auth::user()->name}} <i class="fa fa-user fa-fw"></i><span class="caret"></span></a>
                    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                        <li><a href="{!! url("/user/profile/".Auth::user()->id) !!}">Perfil</a></li>
                        @if(Auth::user()->type_id == 1)
                        <li><a href="{!!URL::to('/user')!!}">Administrar</a></li>
                        @endif
                        <li role="separator" class="divider"></li>
                        <li><a href="{!!URL::to('/logout')!!}"><i class="fa fa-sign-out fa-fw"></i>Logout</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                </ul>
                @endif
                {{-- /.LOGIN --}}
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

I made a `padding-top: 50px;` on the **custom.css**

Comment: Your modal needs to be placed in the document root. Read the [documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just get the modal `div` out of the `<nav>`. I haven't removed all you server checks, so `@if` and etc are visible
[fiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/zhvk7omm/)